# How to make multiple http requests in a WebView

Tags: kotlin, android-webview

I have a string with a large size, and I want to divide this large string into parts, and make a separate request for every part in the list. However, when I try to do that, I get the result only for the last request:

```
     val list =
                    listOf(
                        "Hello",
                        "this will be combined",
                        "I'm testing"
                    )
    
                list.forEach {
                   setupWebView(it, "en", "ckb", webView) 
                }

suspend fun setupWebView(
    input: String,
    from: String,
    into: String,
    webView: WebView
): String {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
        var result = ""


        val url =
            "https://translate.google.com/?sl=$from&tl=$into&text=${input}&op=translate"

        webView.addJavascriptInterface(JsInterface, "JsInterface")

        webView.loadUrl(url)

        JsInterface.setResultCallback {
            result = it
        }


        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true

        webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                view?.postDelayed({
                    injectJavascript(view)
                }, 1000)
            }
        }

        return@withContext result
    }
}
```

I get the result only for "I'm testing". What is the problem with my code? And how to fix it?